# Access 2010 VBA - DAO Database connection "Operation is not supported for this type of object"

Tags: ms-access, vba, database-connection

I'm really stuck.  My coworkers and I cannot figure out why this database won't connect to "CurrentDb".  Here's my code:

```
Dim db As Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strRowSource As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Documents"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)


If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Documents available!"
    Exit Sub
End If

rs.MoveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF = True
    strRowSource = strRowSource & rs!tbl_Documents.DocID & "," & rs!tbl_Document_Types.DocType & "," & rs!tbl_Documents.DocTypeID & "," & rs!tbl_Documents.DateReceived & "," & rs!tbl_Documents.LinkToFile & "," & rs!tbl_Documents.Comments & ";"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Typically the error I get is "Item not found in this collection" during the Do Until loop.  I put a watch on my database and recordset and it seems like neither are being set properly.  I'm getting "Operation is not support for this type of object." in the connection field of the database object.  Essentially, the exact same code is used for many other Access Databases that we have.  Not sure why this won't play nice.

Comment: Did you try `Dim db As DAO.Database` ?

Comment: @Overmind, in the usual libraries, DAO is the only library with a database object, what did you see as the problem? The whole loop code looks very odd to me. Why `rs!tbl_Documents.DocID` rather than `rs!DocID`? What happens to strRowSource? Why are fields not listed in the select statement?

Comment: @Fionnuala Ah, okay. Thanks; I always use it, anyway. I'd have to agree that `strRowSource` looks very odd.

Comment: The field `rs!tbl_Document_Types.DocType` looks extremely odd. You're selecting from `tbl_Documents`, not document types.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like there are quiet a few changes that needs to be done to your code. As @OverMind has suggested, always declare the variables as they are. Specially libraries to avoid ambiguity in your code. Next, your strSQL includes only one table, but your strRowSource has another table. So your strSQL should be changed. I am not sure what the strRowSource does, but sounds to me like it is going to be a RowSource of a ListBox or ComboBox in that case, it is a bit confusing. Anyway your code should be.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String, strRowSource As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_Documents INNER JOIN tbl_Document_Types ON tbl_Documents.DocID = tbl_Document_Types.DocTypeID;"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Documents available!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Do While Not rs.EOF
    strRowSource = strRowSource & rs!DocID & "," & rs!DocType & "," & rs!DocTypeID & "," & rs!DateReceived & "," & rs!LinkToFile & "," & rs!Comments & ";"
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Now regarding your error. "Item not found in this collection" - could be because of the fact you were using the other fields which were not part of the recordset object. Try this code. Good luck. :)